# Return all rows from table1 and corresponding rows from table2 even if null

Tags: sql-server

I'm new into SQL so please bear with me. The question itself is confusing as I don't really know how to ask it. Thing is, I have two tables, table1 lists all printers. Table2 lists their page counters, with year/month parameter. What I want to show is ALL printers with their respective page counters filtered by year/month, and NULL if there is no page counter for that specific printer on that specific time frame. To try and clarify a little, this is what I have:

Table1:

id

model

location

Table2:

id

printerid

counter

year

month

```
SELECT
   tb1.id,
   tb1.model,
   tb1.location,
   tb2.counter
FROM
   table1 tb1 LEFT JOIN table2 tb2 ON tb1.id = tb2.printerid
WHERE
   tb2.year = 2017 AND tb2.month = 1
```

I know the WHERE clause is messing things up, and this query only returns printers that have counters on that year/month parameter. If I remove the WHERE from the query I get duplicates (if a printer has (and will have) counters on different year/months).
What I want is something like this:

```
Printer      Pages      Year      Month
printer1     100        2017      1
printer2     200        2017      1
printer3     null       null      null
```

Instead I'm getting this (without WHERE clause):

```
Printer      Pages      Year      Month
printer1     100        2017      1
printer2     200        2017      1
printer3     null       null      null
printer1     150        2017      2
```

Or this (with WHERE clause):

```
Printer      Pages      Year      Month
printer1     100        2017      1
printer2     200        2017      1
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Although this could be another place to use the ubiquitous (and very useful) tally table construct, there is an easier way to do this in the WHERE clause, e.g. `WHERE ISNULL(tb2.year, 2017) = 2017 AND ISNULL(tb2.month, 1) = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to move the `WHERE` conditions (that involve `table2`) to the joining, `ON` condition:

```
SELECT
   tb1.id,
   tb1.model,
   tb1.location,
   tb2.counter
FROM
   table1 tb1 LEFT JOIN table2 tb2 
   ON (  tb1.id = tb2.printerid
     AND tb2.year = 2017 
     AND tb2.month = 1 
      ) ;
```

The `ON` condition can be as complex as required, it doesn't necessarily be a simple equality, although that's the most common (the parentheses around the condition are not required either, just to make the code a bit more clear).

---

It's unclear how you get `Printer, Pages, Year, Month` columns in the result when you have `id, model, location, counter` in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Yeah, the results clearly don't match the query, I was really confused. Sorry. Your code works like a charm! Didn't know I could use ANDs on the JOINs. Thanks so much! I owe you a beer, or perhaps a coffee.

Comment: You can use any condition, however complex, not a single equality, although it's the most common. Adding parentheses to show more clearly what happens.